# Как прислать массив данных на node.js используя mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Есть такая структура схемы mongo:

```
const User = new Schema({
    email: {type: String, required: true, unique: true},
    password: {type: String, required: true},
    nickname: {type: String, required: true},
    gold: {type: Number, default: 100},
    silver: {type: Number, default: 0},
    level: {type: Number, default: 1},
    builds: [
        {
            name: {type: String, default: 'soybean'},
            position: {type: Number, default: 10},
            isPayed: {type: Boolean, default: false}
        },
        {
            name: {type: String, default: 'corn'},
            position: {type: Number, default: 16},
            isPayed: {type: Boolean, default: false}
        },
        {
            name: {type: String, default: 'sugarcane'},
            position: {type: Number, default: 80},
            isPayed: {type: Boolean, default: false}
        },
        {
        //и далее
```

Затем клиентское приложение обращается к api серверу и просит эти данные
вот обработка:

```
app.get('/game',
    async (req, res) => {
        const token = req.headers.authorization.split('Bearer ')[1]
        const decoded = jwt.verify(token, config.get('secret'))
        req.user = decoded
        const user = await User.findOne({ _id: req.user.id })
        return res.json({
            info: {
                id: user.id,
                nickname: user.nickname,
                email: user.email,
                level: user.level,
                gold: user.gold,
                silver: user.silver
            },
            //Эта строчка кода выводится как пустой массив
            builds: user.builds
           //
            
        })
    })
```

И почему то если сделать запрос, то ответ такой:

```
{info: {…}, builds: Array(0)}
builds: Array(0)
length: 0
__proto__: Array(0)
info:
email: "h@1.eqw"
gold: 100
id: "606b0f6fde83641744882a89"
level: 1
nickname: "qwerty"
silver: 0
__proto__: Object
__proto__: Object
```

массив со зданиями присылается пустым. Как исправить?

Comment: А точно в builds что-то есть? Мб прост массив пустой в базе лежит?

Comment: он не может быть пустым, там же дефолтные значения есть

Comment: А откуда Вы взяли такой синтаксис заполнения массива значениями по умолчанию? Так оно не работает, поэтому и получаете пустой массив. Можете в этом убедиться, подключившись к базе любым клиентом.

Comment: Странно, валюту заполнял таким же систаксисом и в базе есть значения валют, тогда как мне перенести в бд?